# Promotion and conversion in java

Tags: java, casting, type-promotion, type-narrowing

Promotion means to promote or convert the smaller type literals to a higher type. This promotion is used in evaluating expressions. Now I have a doubt regarding this. When i type this statement

```
byte var1 = 56 + 10;
```

Gives the answer 66. How can this be possible? 
According to the promotion rules, every byte, short and char is promoted to int. So this 56 and 10 would be promoted to int and hence the answer 66 would be in int. This 66 would be then stored in a variable of byte type. However to store something from int to byte, casting is to be done. But this code works perfectly without casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is okay because you are giving constant value. See [compile-time narrowing of constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

> The compile-time narrowing of constants means that code such as:
>
> byte theAnswer = 42;
>
> is allowed. Without the narrowing, the fact that the integer literal 42 has type int would mean that a cast to byte would be required:
>
> byte theAnswer = (byte) 42;  // cast is permitted but not required

Answer (score 4):

As in many cases, this is found in the [Java Language Specification § 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

That means that the compiler is first widening to `int` and then narrowing down to the target type, because 66 is indeed representable in the target type (which is byte).

---

Note that this only works for *constant* expressions. For instance, the following code yields a compile-time error:

```
static int get() {
    return 10;
}

public static final main(String[] args) {
    byte var1 = 56 + get();
}
```